# Check if there are at least 2 rows for a query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a better way to check if there are at least two rows in a table for a given condition?

Please look at this PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE .......");
$has_2_rows = (mysql_result($result, 0) >= 2);
```

The reason I dislike this, is because I assume MySQL will get and count ALL the matching rows, which can be slow for large results.

I would like to know if there is a way that MySQL will stop and return "1" or true when two rows are found. Would a `LIMIT 2` at the end help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question, and yes there is a way to make this very efficient even for large tables.

Use this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table
    WHERE .......
    LIMIT 2
) x
```

All the work is done by the inner query, which stops when it gets 2 rows. Also note the `select 1`, which gives you a tiny bit more efficiency, since it doesn't have to retrieve any values from columns - just the constant `1`.

The outer `count(*)` will count at most 2 rows.

Note: Since this is an SQL question, I've omitted PHP code from the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This answered to my question, and +1 for the SQL-only approach.

Answer (score 1):

The query below will only inspect two rows as you request.  `mysql_num_rows` can check how many rows are returned without any looping.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT col1 FROM t1 WHERE ... LIMIT 2");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 2) {
```

---

Please avoid using `ext/mysql` and switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` if you can.

Comment: I use "mysqli" at the moment. It doesn't matter what I used in the question, as that is not what the question is about.

Comment: @NunoPeralta why did you only read the second part of the question?  I even used a horizontal rule to divide my actual answer from the advice?  You would think you would read the *first* part of the question first...  I even use `ext/mysql` in my answer!

Comment: I was now editing my comment, because only now I noticed that the first part is not a quote from my code. I recommend you to edit your answer to add something like "Please try this:", and probably also explain why did you use that approach. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE .......");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1) 
{
 echo 'at least 2 rows';
}

else
{
 echo 'less than 2 rows';
}
```